# How to parse list return value into sympy expression which you can substitute values in?

Tags: parsing, return, sympy, substitution

Hey I am new to using sympy and I have a problem working with the return value of solve(), because it always gives back a list
instead of a sympy expression. I want to substitute values into
my solution using sol.subs() which only works for sympy expressions. Can anyone tell me how to do this ?

eq1 = sp.Eq(sp.sqrt(2 * m * E) / h_bar, n * pi)
E_n = sp.solve(eq1, E)

type(E_n) is a list now. I want to use continue using it
as an expression. For example:

E_1 = E_n.subs(n, 1)
E_2 = E_n.subs(n, 2)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the element from the list with `[0]` i.e.:

```
In [19]: import sympy as sp

In [20]: m, E, h_bar, n = sp.symbols('m, E, h_bar, n', positive=True)

In [21]: eq1 = sp.Eq(sp.sqrt(2 * m * E) / h_bar, n * pi)

In [22]: E_n = solve(eq1, E)[0]

In [23]: E_n
Out[23]: 
 2      2  2
π ⋅h_bar ⋅n 
────────────
    2⋅m     

In [24]: E_n.subs(n, 1)
Out[24]: 
 2      2
π ⋅h_bar 
─────────
   2⋅m
```